# pgrwithpointscost returning empty table

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I have a road network and points along the road network that I would like to calculate the distances of the points from beginning to end.  Previously @geozelot helped me with a similar problem, but this time it returns an empty table.

The files are located here: https://github.com/EPPResponse/pgrwithpoints-problem

I have the following code to clean up the lines and points:

```
-- << Cleanup up old topological references >>

-- remove old vertices table
DROP TABLE
test.roads_vertices_pgr
;

-- -- remove old topology refs
UPDATE
test.roads
SET source = NULL,
target = NULL
;

-- drop indexes
DROP INDEX
test.roads_geom_idx
;
DROP INDEX
test.roads_source_idx
;
DROP INDEX
test.roads_target_idx
;

-- << Force 2D linesegment and place in new geom column >>
ALTER TABLE test.roads 
  ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(LINESTRING, 26911) 
    USING ST_Force2D(geom);     

-- change geometry type to LINESTRING

ALTER TABLE
test.roads
ALTER COLUMN
geom TYPE GEOMETRY(LINESTRING, 26911) USING ST_GeometryN(geom, 1)
;

ALTER TABLE test.roads ADD COLUMN "source" integer; -- add source column for pg routing
ALTER TABLE test.roads ADD COLUMN "target" integer; -- add target column for pg routing

SELECT pgr_createTopology('test.roads', 0.0001, 'geom'); -- prepare stream layer using pg routing builder to build a network topology based on the geometry information.

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.distance_cost;
    CREATE TABLE test.distance_cost AS 
    SELECT
    cmx.*,
    pts.*
    FROM
    pgr_withPointsCost(
    -- Edge SQL - populating 'cost'/'reverse_cost' on the fly
    $$
    SELECT
    id,                                         -- IMPORTANT: *** id field must be integer type ***
    source,
    target,
    ST_Length(geom) AS cost,
    -1 AS reverse_cost
    FROM
    test.roads
    $$,
    -- Point SQL - populating 'fraction' on the fly (via (K)NN sub-query)
    $$
    SELECT
    pts.id AS pid,
    stm.id AS edge_id,
    CASE WHEN stm._frac = 0.0 THEN 0.000001 WHEN stm._frac = 1.0 THEN 0.99999999 ELSE stm._frac END AS fraction
    FROM
    test.ccp_move AS pts                                -- *** Points to calculate distances from & to ***
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
    _stm.id,
    ST_LineLocatePoint(_stm.geom, pts.geom) AS _frac
    FROM
    test.roads AS _stm
    ORDER BY
    _stm.geom <-> pts.geom
    LIMIT
    1
    ) AS stm
    $$,
    -- 'start_pid' - negating on the fly
    (
    SELECT
    -id
    FROM
    test.ccp_move                           -- ccp table name
    WHERE
    id = 1
    ),
    -- 'end_pids' - negating on the fly
    (
    SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG(-id)
    FROM
    test.ccp_move                           -- ccp table name
    WHERE
    id > 1
    ),
    directed := TRUE
    ) AS cmx
    LEFT JOIN
    test.ccp_move AS pts                    -- ccp table name
    ON -(cmx.end_pid) = pts.id -- -(-n) = n
    ;
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to use your provided files but for roads, I am getting `Invalid Data Source: roads.shp is not a valid or recognized data source.` It seems the `roads.shx` file is missing.

Comment: @TimothyDalton `QGIS -> Toolbox -> 'Repair Shapefile'`

Comment: Looks to me like directionality (`directed := TRUE`) won't work here - you can't go from `ccp_move.id = 1` to any other on a directed graph!

Comment: uploaded new data.zip.

Comment: @geozelot solved.  Thank you.  I have lots to learn.

Comment: @geozelot I came back to your comment and don't really understand it.  The graph I have is a directed stream and I thought it would naturally follow the line from an initial point (id = 1) to any other point downstream of it (directed or not).  Why does it matter if the directed = True or False is set?

Comment: The topology is created with respect to the LineString *direction* - a line has a first point and a last point, always, and *pgRouting* assigns the start and end nodes accordingly. On a *directed* graph you can traverse edges in one direction only, and within a *pgRouting* topology this indirectly corresponds to the direction of the LineString. There is more behind all this, but you got the gist of it - it looks like your LineStrings are not properly oriented to support the *down-stream* direction.